# Implement OAuth2.0 Auth Server using Spring Security Framework with Client Side Login Form

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am currently trying to implement an OAuth2.0 Authorization Server using Spring Security Framework:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My initial implementation is following the standard Auhtorization Code With PKCE flow:

1. Client would have to first call the Authorization Endpoint of my Auth Server e.g.:

```
https://authorization-server.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=zMP_79LS2UPtyFa1z0TrdwoN&redirect_uri=https://www.oauth.com/playground/authorization-code-with-pkce.html&scope=photo+offline_access&state=0OaV1kmkkK8yFbqe&code_challenge=WVe6cGEQGlHk3hXXpyUo4hvs2uzCg4j3-oXfnX9L6HA&code_challenge_method=S256
```

2. The Auth Server will render a login form to authenticate the user.
3. Then the Auth Server would reply with the Authorization Code to the redirect uri(client)
4. Client would send another request back to the Auth Server. This time around, it will call the Token endpoint, supplying the Authorization Code received from Step 3.

```
https://authorization-server.com/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=zMP_79LS2UPtyFa1z0TrdwoN&client_secret=VvfjKzAWIr0bxWKTUvzC48NkzlhwnAuSOsWOb6C8AdG7GH5O&redirect_uri=https://www.oauth.com/playground/authorization-code-with-pkce.html&code=z9dJErNexuAL0VRaOu9AfxhMuOJL-IT7zY5HILeKFW5XmFOT&code_verifier=Q3TsNTc5__76nzRtp43zjVJ3yxD_P1WD-khqJ7rdTxS_l73w
```

5. The Auth Server will now reply with the Access Token

So far so good. Everything works out.

But now I want to alter the behavior and let the client(front end using react) render the login form instead of the Auth Server:

1. Client renders login form.
2. Client sends username/password to backend by calling backend RESTful API(/auth/login)

Is it feasible to integrate this behavior to the OAuth2.0 Spring Security Framework? What I want to do is from the RESTful API endpoint:

1. I would authenticate the user by using a customized Authentication Provider
2. Inject the authenticated user into the OAuth2.0 framework and let it ride along the framework so that the Auth Server would still send an Authorization Code to the redirect uri without having to render a login form on the backend side since the username/password has already been supplied by the frontend.

Thank you very much.

What I tried so far:

1. Create a customized Authentication Handler to authenticate the username/password

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    private final CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        builder.userDetailsService(customUserDetailService);
        builder.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);

        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

```
@Service
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    private final CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        E2AuthUserDetails user = (E2AuthUserDetails) customUserDetailService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        return checkPassword(user, password);
    }

    private Authentication checkPassword(UserDetails user, String rawLoginPassword) {
        String dbPassword = user.getPassword();
        if (passwordEncoder.matches(rawLoginPassword, dbPassword)) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(),
                    dbPassword,
                    user.getAuthorities());
        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad Credentials");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}
```

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthService {
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public LoginResponse attemptLogin(String email, String password) {
        var authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, password)
        );
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    }
}
```

2. Setup AuthorizationServer configuration

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class AuthorizationServerConfig {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    // Add a customized security filter and set this as the first in the chain
    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

        return http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    }

    // Customize client registration
    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("client")
                .clientSecret(passwordEncoder.encode("secret"))
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .redirectUri("http://spring.io/auth")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .build();


        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }

    // Setup OAuth endpoints and other default config
    @Bean
    public ProviderSettings providerSettings() {
        return ProviderSettings.builder()
                //.issuer("http://auth-server:9000")
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Collecting user credentials on client and sending it to the authorization server would be `password` flow. Don't do that: it was deprecated for security reasons. Stick to the `authorization_code` flow and style the login form on your authorization server to keep the look and feel of your app.

Also, React apps (as well as any other single page or mobile application) make unsafe OAuth2 clients. As per [latest recommendations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390), OAuth2 clients should run on your server and be "confidential". Requests from the the frontend (React in your case) to the backend entry-point (a "BFF") would be authorized with session. As BFF, you might use `spring-cloud-gateway` with `oauth2Login` and the `TokenRelay` filter. **I wrote [a tutorial for that on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2).**